# Sabre XML Writer - Group repeating Elements

Tags: php, xml, serialization

I have a little question for sabre xml.

I prefer not to develop custom writers hardcoded for every PHP Class I want to serialize, so I use the mapValueObject to tell SabreXML what to do.
Unfortunatelly my repeating elements are not grouped.

I have a PHP Model which would look like this (simplified):

class ProductItem contains an object of the class "Product" and an array, containing multiple ProductsDescriptions for multilanguage.

```
class ProductItem extends Model {
  /**
   * @var Product
   */
  var $Product;
  /**
   * @var ProductsDescription[]
   */
  var $descriptions;
}
```

class Model contains the information how to serialize the extending classes.

```
abstract Model {
  public function Serialize() {
    $service = new \Sabre\Xml\Service();
    $service->mapValueObject('{}ProductItem', ProductItem::class);
    $service->mapValueObject('{}Product', Product::class);
    $service->mapValueObject('{}ProductsDescription', ProductsDescription::class);
    $xml = $service->writeValueObject($this);
    return $xml;
  }
}
```

The XML returned looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ProductItem>
  <Product>
    <Id>1234</Id>
    <Stock>100</Stock>
  </Product>
  <descriptions>
    <Language_code>deu</Language_code>
    <Products_name>TestDEU</Products_name>
  </descriptions>
  <descriptions>
    <Language_code>eng</Language_code>
    <Products_name>TestENG</Products_name>
  </descriptions>
</ProductItem>
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ProductItem>
  <Product>
    <Id>1234</Id>
    <Stock>100</Stock>
  </Product>
  <descriptions>
    <ProductsDescription>
      <Language_code>deu</Language_code>
      <Products_name>TestDEU</Products_name>
    </ProductsDescription>
    <ProductsDescription>
      <Products<Language_code>eng</Language_code>
      <Products_name>TestENG</Products_name>
    </ProductsDesription>
  </descriptions>
</ProductItem>
```

Is there a way how to tell SabreXML to group the repeating Elements of a certain class by using the mapValueObjects, or do I have to write a custom serializer for my class ProductItem, which would collect all the children, sets them in to an array and serializes them using the

```
Sabre\Xml\Serializer\repeatingElements($writer, $collection, 'childname');
```

function?

Comment: Hey @Mandalorserbe you get any solution on this question? If you get then share in this questions answer..

Comment: Hi @kupendra no I did not find a solution, so I switched to another XML Serializer (JMS) https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer


Sorry for the late answer

Comment: Thanks for replay @Mandalorserbe